# DICOM: What's the point of SOPInstanceUID tag?

Tags: dicom

DICOM already provides a unique enough identifier for the Series (e.g. [`Series Instance UID`](http://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/rt-structure-set/rt-series/0020000e)), so why also include one on the lower level objects (e.g. [`SOPInstanceUID`](http://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/rt-structure-set/sop-common/00080018))?

What I find really annoying is the fact that when referencing other objects - for example when `RTPlan` object references `RTStruct` object via [`ReferencedStructureSetSequence`](http://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/rt-plan/rt-general-plan/300c0060) / `ReferencedSOPInstanceUID` - it's done using the `SOP Instance UID`.  However any of the DICOM SCPs - such as find/move - don't work with `SOP Instance UID`, they work with the `Series Instance UID`.  So what gives?  Do I have to load the whole `Series` to find all the referenced objects?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you probably know, DICOM has a hierarchy of identifiers for each individual SOP (Service Object Pair) Instance (Patient ID / Study Instance UID / Series Instance UID / SOP Instance UID).  This hierarchy is built into the Query/Retrieve mechanism in DICOM, and is also used to identify specific SOP Instances.

In the specific case you're mentioning, I believe there could be the possibility of multiple RT Structure Sets within a Series/Study.  The individual SOP Instance must be referenced so that you know which Structure Set the RT Plan is referencing.

As for products supporting retrieving by SOP Instance UID, unfortunately, relational queries are not widely supported in DICOM Query/Retrieve SCPs, as you've discovered, and some DICOM servers do not support Image level queries.  In this specific case, you could query at the series level specifically for the RTSTRUCT modality, and only retrieve the Series that have this modality, thus narrowing down which data you need to download to just the RT Structure Sets.

Comment: In my experience there is only one RT object per SeriesInstanceUID.  That is why it seems to me like a SeriesInstanceUID is a good enough identifier.  For images, I can see the need for another level if ID to identify each image uniquely.

It just seems strange how pathetic Query/Retreive specification really is, and how little you need to support to comply.

Comment: @Budric-- I've often seen multiple RT structs for a single CT series-- for instance, to have multiple doctors mark the same patient to arrive at some definition of 'ground truth' (see Warfield).

Answer (score 56):

This question was from quite a while ago, but I thought I'd add that, ignoring `QR` altogether, a [`SeriesInstanceUID`](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part03.html#table_C.7-5a) is a globally unique identifier for a single series.  [`SOPInstanceUID`](http://dicom.nema.org/Dicom/2013/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.12.html#table_C.12-1) is a globally unique identifier for a `DICOM` file.  A series can have multiple `DICOM` files, so each would share that same `SeriesInstanceUID`, but each file would have it's own `SOPInstanceUID`.

Answer (score 5):

SOPInstanceUID represent separate uid of the Dicom Image File. Study, series and sopinstace uids are based on data model. StudyUID give you the particular study information. In which different series devided. Series instance uid used for for this. And SOP instance uid represent seperate Dicom image. It's hierarchy structure. I also never used SOPInstanceUID when i developed PACS workstation in Java. As per my experience, Study & Series uids are enough for represent patient's data. But still SOPInstanceUID gives unique identity to dicom image.

Comment: `SOPInstanceUID` represents a globally unique `DICOM` file. That does not directly correlate with a single image. A `DICOM` file may contain a single image, it may contain multiple images, or it may contain no image at all (`SR`, for example)

Answer (score 4):

SOP Instance UID : Represent your a unique Identifier for IOD, Its a **TYPE 1** tag must present with value.

For Example :

Each DICOM Image has unique identifier

Answer (score 4):

SOPInstanceUId is for image level identification.

***Understand it like:***
A **study** can have **multiple series** and a series can have **multiple images/DICOM**

---

So,

to identify **study** uniquely we use StudyInstanceUID

---

to identify **series** uniquely we use SeriesInstanceUID and

---

to identify **an image/DICOM** uniquely we use SOPInstanceUId

Comment: `SOPInstanceUID` does not identify an image. As commented above - `SOPInstanceUID` represents a globally unique `DICOM` file. That does not directly correlate with a single image. A `DICOM` file may contain a single image, it may contain multiple images, or it may contain no image at all (`SR`, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Series reference is not specific enough.  In the case of structure sets the Reference SOP Instance UID ties the contours in the structure set to the specific slice in the dataset.  It's not enough to just reference the series because you have to ensure that the contour is exactly aligning with a slice.