# How to identify a dicom data file

Tags: dicom

All, Forgive me I am a newbie in the `DICOM`, I want to know how to identify a DICOM data file. I am not sure whether the combination of `PatientID + StudyID + SeriesNumber+ InstanceNumber` could work? Please help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434918/dicom-whats-the-point-of-sopinstanceuid-tag this post is helpful.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.protocols.dicom/xh0ogPv31aI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

According to the DICOM Standard the SOPInstanceUID (0008,0018) is sufficient to uniquely identify a DICOM object.

In practice, it turns out that you are better off using a hierarchical method based on the UIDs of the levels above. These are

Patient-ID (0010,0020)
StudyInstanceUID (0020,000D)
SeriesInstanceUID (0020,000E)
SOPInstanceUID (0008,0018)

Comment: +1, Sorry for my another question. Who generates the SOPInstanceUID? Pacs or Modality? And How is it generated uniquely?

Comment: The device which acquires the data always assigns the SOPInstanceUID. The uniqueness is guaranteed either by using a particular algorithm or by a UID scheme which uses a officially registered, vendor-specific prefix and a vendor specific suffix generation algorithm.

Comment: Got it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I confirm. This is actually the approach that is adopted by the [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/) VNA. Implementation details are available in the FAQ of the [Orthanc Book](https://orthanc.chu.ulg.ac.be/book/faq/orthanc-ids.html).

Comment: @Tisys Thanks your confirming.